# How do I stop my cat stealing food?

Tags: cats, diet

I have a 6 month old Maine coon kitten and he is so full of personality and craves attention (which he gets plenty of, there’s someone home 24/7).

He’s developed a behaviour where he will steal food. I mean rooting through the bin for scraps, persistently trying to eat off our and our toddlers plates (resulting in scratches) and even stealing snacks right next to us. We never let him actually get the food trying not to reinforce it.

He’s fed on purrform raw food, based on weight recommended by his breeder twice a day. He also had access to Purina dry food and fresh water all day. He has a LOT of play time to alleviate boredom and we’re at a loss why he does it and how we can reduce it. Anyone had this and any success in stopping it? TIA

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Do you feed him according to recommendations for adult cats or for kittens? At 6 months of age he's not an infant anymore, but he's still growing and very active, so he probably needs more than the recommended food or alternatively a food specifically formulated for kittens.

Comment: In addition to @Elmy 's comments, if the cat is in fact a Maine Coon (not "cat that looks like he might be), they take longer to mature than regular cats, and will have higher calorie needs for longer than the average DSH/DLH